# select checkboxes from a list using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I select checkboxes that have their id in a list or array? lets say I have a list of IDs

```
var selected = 'chkbx_0,chkbx_3' 

<div id="optionList">
<input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="c_n_0" />Option 1
<input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="c_n_1" />Option 2
<input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="c_n_2" />Option 3
<input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="c_n_3" />Option 4
</div>
```

so when I run the function I want whatever is in the list selected only in that particular div
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what the end result is supposed to be.

Comment: so checkbx_0 and checkbx_3 should be selected?

Comment: the end result will display chkbx_0 and chkbx_3 checked because they are in the selected string or make it an array

Comment: yes- so checkbx_0 and checkbx_3 should be selected

Comment: make it array, and run the loop to get single id,  and using jquery you can set that particular checkbox to set checked

Comment: Thanks Manny- sometimes the most obvious gets missed because I'm looking for a more complicated method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make your list an array, then it becomes quite simple:

```
var idList = ["chkbx_0", "chkbx_3"];
for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++)
{
  $("#" + idList[i]).prop("checked", true);
}
```

Even if you can't make the initial list into an array, you can fairly easily turn it into one as a preliminary step:

```
var selected = 'chkbx_0,chkbx_3';
var idList = selected.split(","); //split the list on every comma, into an array
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var selected = 'chkbx_0,chkbx_3'; 

//split into array using split function
var arr = selected.split(',');

// here to find the length of array
var len = arr.length;

//for loop to checked the each string in array
for(var i=0; i<=len; i++){
 $('#'+arr[i]).attr('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionList">
  <input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="c_n_0" />Option 1
  <input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="c_n_1" />Option 2
  <input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="c_n_2" />Option 3
  <input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="c_n_3" />Option 4
</div>
```

[Click here to check working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/0k22oumd/10/)

Comment: The JSFiddle is not needed with the integrated snippet. Also, consider explaining your answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

**Code explanation**

`var selected_arr = selected.split(',');` : here I'm splitting your comma separated items into an array

```
$('#optionList input').each(function(){
    if( selected_arr.includes($(this).attr('id')) )
    {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

In the above function, we are looping through all the inputs (checkboxes) in the specified div, and checking if their `id` is present in the array we created. If it is present, we select that checkbox.

```js
var selected = 'chkbx_0,chkbx_3' ;

var selected_arr = selected.split(',');

$('#optionList input').each(function(){
    if( selected_arr.includes($(this).attr('id')) )
    {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="optionList">
<input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="c_n_0" />Option 1
<input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="c_n_1" />Option 2
<input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="c_n_2" />Option 3
<input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="c_n_3" />Option 4
</div>
```